# Which device is used for intra-localhost traffic?

Tags: windows, networking, wireshark, winpcap

Meet A and B, two apps running locally on my Windows box. A is listening on port [whatever], B is connecting to localhost:[whatever]
Although I can see traffic being sent by A and received by B, Wireshark (and winpcap) shows no activity on any network adapter.
What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application B is connecting to the so called "loopback" interface. [Here](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback) is an explanation on how to setup loopback capture in Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can capture local traffic with the likes of Wireshark on Windows: [http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback](http:////http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback)